# Spring Boot application exits immediately when I autowire components of another jar

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I have a executable jar file ("A") which has some controllers, services etc. This application depends on another project ("B") which I have added as a dependency in the application's pom file. Project B does not have any controllers. It just has some service methods.

Now, when I autowire some fields from project B in project A and then try to start project A, it exits immediately with a message

```
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:49447', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

However, when I remove the autowiring and then try to start, it starts normally. Why does this happen? Just a note that project A uses Spring 1.5, whereas project B is in Spring boot 1.3. Also, I have other projects which also use project B as a dependency, but they are working fine.

I've tried adding logs:

```
logging.level.root=WARN
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate=ERROR
```

But it doesn't print anything.

Comment: Logging is your friend in this case. What do the logs say?

Comment: I do not see any logs. I have added these lines: `logging.level.root=WARN
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate=ERROR`, but it doesn't say anything.

Comment: Sorry, looks like it was logging to an external file. Found out what the problem was.

Comment: You will need to provide more information, but in general I would suggest a work around as encapsulating the dependent project as a standalone REST service which you would call yourself.

Comment: @drunkenfist would you mind providing the info about the problem and the fix? Thanks!